# Stuck on a program creation assignment utilising Visual C++,

Tags: c++

I am Brand New to programming, I`enter code here` have an assignment to do, based on this image and question here, " A local electronics store allows items to be purchased on hire purchase. The hire purchase option
requires a deposit of one fifth of the cash price. There is an interest charge of 10% on the
balance.
Consider the following example: A customer wishes to purchase a Dell Inspiron 15-inch laptop,
with an i5 processor and 8 GB RAM, for $3500. The item code is 12345 and the customer
chooses to pay via two years of hire purchase.
The program operates as follows:
Write a program, HirePurchase, which prints the invoice for an item on hire purchase as
detailed above. The program prompts for the item code, cash price and the number of years on hire
purchase. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFzOa.png)

I have begun but every time I try to run the program only a piece of it presents itself on screen. I'm very sorry if this seems basic but I'm interested in programming.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main () {
    int NumberMonthHirePurchase,ItemCode,NumberYearHirePurchase;
    double CashPrice,Deposit,MonthlyInstall,NewbalanceOne, NewBalanceTwo;
    cout<<"Please enter the Item Code:2768N3496YHG";
    cin>>ItemCode;
    cout<<"Please enter the cash price of the item:6,264";
    cin>>CashPrice;
    cout<<"Please enter the Number of Years Hire Purchase:1";
    cin>>NumberYearHirePurchase;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"item details"<<endl;
    cout<<"Item code:2768N3496YHG"<<ItemCode<<endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

this is what I have so far but only "please enter the item code" is appearing and nothing else. I don't know if it's because I am doing something wrong, can someone please assist, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wherever you are learning this from looks dubious, as does the choice of C++ as a first programming language.

Comment: Those numbers at the end of the lines are supposed to be input by the user. Are you entering anything into the console window?

Comment: Looks like your program stops to receive input from you. Are you providing any? If yes and it still not working, [Visual Studio has a world-class debugger built into to it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt.aspx). With it you can execute your program line by line and see where it stopped.

Comment: When you say 'only "please enter the item code" is appearing' I don't believe you.  I am sure that what is appearing is "Please enter the Item Code:2768N3496YHG".  Note that this has three capital letters and the trailing code.

Comment: sorry my bad, I meant, yeah the 2768N3496YHG is appearing as well but that's it, nothing else. sorry

Comment: and they told us to use Dev C++, should i use Visual Studio instead?

Comment: @RobertoBarasa: Who are "they"? Yes, I think DevC++ sucks and Visual Studio is much better as an IDE. However, you probably shouldn't use an IDE at all if you are so new to programming. Use a text editor and the command line to invoke Visual C++. That's how you really learn how things work.

Comment: oh," they"are the people I asked for help back home where 'Im from, Trinidad and Tobago. and thanks by the way. sorry if this seems like nonsensical to you all. I am just really confused and would like to get further along. I do economics as my study, but i know the way the world is going, Computer science, programming and what not are great to have an understanding of, for the least.

Comment: I dislike the text editor, but Visual Studio's debugger is top notch. A debugger that's easy to pick up and use is worth it's weight in neutronium to a programmer trying to find their footing.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `ItemCode` is an `int`. That means `cin>>ItemCode` will read only `2768` from the input. The rest of the input, `N3496YHG`, will be left in the input buffer for the remaining input to read.

However, since the next input is to read a floating point value, and `N3496YHG` is not a valid floating point value, nothing will be read and an error flag will be set on the input stream.

Since the error flag is now set on the stream, the third attempt to read something (the integer for `NumberYearHirePurchase`) will not do anything at all.

To solve this, the `ItemCode` should be a string, using `std::string`.

Also note that input of floating-point values doesn't have to use the comma `,` as decimal separator. It depends on the settings of your computer.

---

Of course, the above is only valid if you actually try to input something. If you don't input anything, the program will appear to stand still as it patiently waits for your input.

Comment: Brilliant!  That's not quite psychic debugging, but it's close.

Comment: I really do appreciate all of this, i"ll go and try some more. thank you very much